# Convert NSString representing an array of arrays of numbers to NSArray

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray, text-parsing

I am receiving a string in my request; the string is a list of pairs of numbers, grouped with square brackets. (The list represents polygons to display inside my app.)

I need to convert it to an `NSArray` and parse all the numbers into coordinates.

The received string is

```
[[[53.502483, -113.420593], [53.503429, -113.421527], [53.503491, -113.421673], [53.503002, -113.42164], [53.502719, -113.421426], [53.502483, -113.420593]]]
```

All the examples I've found are just to convert a single list in text to `NSArray`. I couldn't find anything where there are multiple arrays in the string.

Comment: You need a regex to get the string in between [ ], and then split the string based on comma (,) and add the result to array. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri No, you don't *need* a regex. There are several other ways to parse the string.

Comment: @rmaddy  you guys are taking everything too literally :P . Yes there are other ways too.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Of course we take things literally. We are programmers. It's a requirement for us to be exact and clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string looks like valid JSON, so...

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:&error];
```

Will give the array, provided `string` contains the input.  If it's coming from a web request, you can save a step and convert the request's `NSData` directly.

Comment: I was doing that and the polygon was not drawn on the map. After 20 minutes  of posting this question, i discovered that the server is returning the latitude instead of longitude and vice versa ..aghhh 2 hours of searching for nothing..Thank you for your reply and I will mark it as an answer for your help :)